# How to fetch session Id in Rest Assuered

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am trying to fetch session id of the user but the session id is coming as null. Below is the sample code I have used

```
RestAssured.baseURI="https://demo.com"
Response response = RestAssured.given().
header("Content-Type","application/json").header("connection","keep-alive").header("Accept-Encoding","gzp,deflate,br")
.body(" {n" +
            ""usename": "demo",n" +
            ""email": "demo@abc.com"n" +
            "}")
.post("/login\r\n");

System.out.println(response.getSessionId());
System.out.println(response.getCookies());
```

I am expecting the session id and cookie of user logged in but I am getting value as null.

Comment: How is the cookie named that stores your session id?

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: Session id is propagated to your client from the sever after you have logged in with a dedicated cookie. Its name might differ from feamework to framework (on backend side). More over frameworks allow to customize that cookie's name. So in order to fetch session id you have to know how exactly it is stored for your case.

Comment: your json in body is incorrect and path in post method is wrong as well. Are you sure that your code is compiled successfully???